# why does my nextjs app get ECONREFUSED randomly?

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I have a pretty simple NextJS 13 app with `/app` directory, and `/app/api/test/route.ts`

nine times out of ten, the app works fine, but every so often I get this error:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:64234
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1494:16)
    at TCPConnectWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17) {
  errno: -61,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 64234
}
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:64234
```

what could be causing this? I am not trying to access that port at all in the code -- could it be an issue with the middleware or the `/api` routes?

I thought [this](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/13316) was the solution, but I am still encountering this error. It happens with and without middleware.